# Function is not able to return elements in returnSize array in the problem

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, pointers

I tried to solve a C coding problem Two Sum in Online coding platform LeetCode
I am not able to return the integer pointer size.

Question:
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target. You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int i,j,sum=0,n1=0,n2=0,sz=1;
    int *re;
    re = (int*)malloc(sizeof(returnSize));

    for(i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
        
         if(sum==target){
                break;
         }

         n1 = i;
         for(j=i+1;j<numsSize;j++){
              sum = nums[i]+nums[j];
            
              if(sum==target){
                   n2 = j;
                   re[0] = n1;
                   re[1] = n2;
                   break;
              }
         }  
    }
    
    return re;
}
```

“I expect the output of `nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]`, `target = 9`, to be `[0, 1]`, but the actual output is `]`”

Comment: Also note that the contents of the memory you allocate isn't always initialized.

Comment: You are not supposed to return the array by overwriting `returnSize`. You are supposed to return the size of the returned array by writing it to the variable referred by `returnSize`.

Comment: LeetCode’s problem statement is defective. It fails to state what the `returnSize` parameter is for and, if it is for the size of the returned array, whether the units are elements or bytes. And, since the size is necessarily two elements, it is not clear why there is a parameter to wastefully return this constant.

Answer (score 1):

The interface of the function is designed to provide a two-part result, the array and its size.
You are not supposed to return the array by overwriting `returnSize`.
You are supposed to return the size of the returned array by writing it to the int variable referred by the pointer `returnSize` (and probably check that it is not a NULL pointer).

The array (i.e. the newly malloced pointer) is supposed to be returned via `return`, which of course you do. But doing that by overwriting return parameter pointer is what indirectly causes a problem here. (A [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be required to trace the observed problem to this.)

By the way, I spotted this simply by seeing that you ignore and overwrite one of the parameters, the pointer. If that were correct, then the interface of the function would be inefficient. That can be the case, but usually not for challenges.

Comment: The problem is inadequately stated. The interface is inefficient regardless because the necessary size is already known to be two elements. And the problem does not state whether the size is given in units of elements or bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce the problem for the provided array. But in any case the function is incorrect..

Instead of this statement (where the argument of the malloc call does not make sense)

```
re = (int*)malloc(sizeof(returnSize));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

there should be

```
re = (int*)malloc(sizeof( sizeof( int ) * *returnSize ));
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Though the parameter `returnSize` is redundant because the array according to your description has a fixed size equal to 2.

Moreover there is an unused variable `sz=1`

The function can invoke undefined behavior because in the case when the `target` is equal to `0` then the dynamically allocated array is not initialized and has indeterminate values because there is exit from the loop.

```
for(i=0;i<numsSize;i++){

     if(sum==target){
            break;
        }
    // ...
```

There is no need to dynamically allocate an array. You could return a structure of two elements.

The first parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

The function can be written simpler and more clear and readable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct PairIndices
{
    size_t first;
    size_t second;
};

struct PairIndices twoSum( const int *a, size_t n, int target )
{
    struct PairIndices pair = { n, n };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n && pair.first == n ; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 1;

        while ( j < n && a[i] + a[j] != target ) j++;

        if ( j != n )
        {
            pair.first  = i;
            pair.second = j;
        }
    }

    return pair;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 2, 7, 11, 15 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    int target = 9;

    struct PairIndices pair = twoSum( a, N, target );

    if ( pair.first != N )
    {
        printf( "a[%zu] + a[%zu] == %d\n", pair.first, pair.second, target );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "There are no two elements in the array "
                "sum of which is equal to %d\n", target );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a[0] + a[1] == 9
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int *result = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    *returnSize=2;
    for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<numsSize;j++){
            if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target){
                result[0]=i;
                result[1]=j;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Especially for homework problems, coding challenges like LeetCode, etc., it's nicer to answer the OP's specific question about the problem than to just solve the problem for them.